# Error when installed Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I've install Yii2 framework using composer but get this error in my browser (on localhost):

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>
> yii\web\Request::cookieValidationKey must be configured with a secret key.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is this problem with basic app now https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/issues/69 where `composer install` doesn't generate this key.

You need to add this key manually.

1. Go to /config/web.php.
2. Edit the line `'cookieValidationKey' => '',` to include random string (you can use anything like `'cookieValidationKey' => 'jfsbkjsbfdskjgfdskjbgfsdhjgfajds',`

Comment: This solution is not working for me. Kindly see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60204467/yii2-invalid-configuration-cookievalidationkey-must-be-configured-with-a-secret) on it

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You need to set `cookieValidationKey` value in `project/config/web.php` at line 12.

change at:

```
'cookieValidationKey' => '',
```

replace with:

```
'cookieValidationKey' => 'setyourkey',
```

[image]

That should address the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `cookieValidationKey` in the config file to a random string. The config file is located under `yii/your-projectfolder/config/main-local.php` if you are using Yii 2.0 Advanced Template

Comment: i use basic template

Comment: Look for `config/web.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
open Frontend/ config / main.php

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'enableCookieValidation' => true,
        'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
        // 'cookieValidationKey' => 'xxxxxxx', // if u dont hv key just comment it 
    ],
],
```

if you have a web.php

```
'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'enableCookieValidation' => true,
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'your-validation-key',
        ],
```