# Yii2 Invalid Configuration, cookieValidationKey must be configured with a secret key error when accessing the API

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app

I am encountering an error whenever I am trying to access my self written API.

> {
>       "name": "Invalid Configuration",
>       "message": "yii\web\Request::cookieValidationKey must be configured with a secret key.",
>       "code": 0,
>       "type": "yii\base\InvalidConfigException",
>       "file": "F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php",
>       "line": 1669,
>       "stack-trace": [
>           "#0 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php(1651): yii\web\Request->loadCookies()",
>           "#1 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php(1739): yii\web\Request->getCookies()",
>           "#2 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php(1721): yii\web\Request->loadCsrfToken()",
>           "#3 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php(279): yii\web\Request->getCsrfToken(true)",
>           "#4 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php(261): yii\web\User->regenerateCsrfToken()",
>           "#5 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php(299): yii\web\User->login(Object(common\models\User))",
>           "#6 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\auth\HttpHeaderAuth.php(62): yii\web\User->loginByAccessToken('aa9d0c9e05a7f35...', 'yii\\filters\\aut...')",
>           "#7 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\auth\AuthMethod.php(59): yii\filters\auth\HttpHeaderAuth->authenticate(Object(yii\web\User), Object(yii\web\Request), Object(yii\web\Response))",
>           "#8 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ActionFilter.php(77): yii\filters\auth\AuthMethod->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))",
>           "#9 [internal function]: yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))",
>           "#10 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(627): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))",
>           "#11 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(276): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))",
>           "#12 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php(185): yii\base\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))",
>           "#13 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(155): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))",
>           "#14 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('refdatajson', Array)",
>           "#15 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('v1/survey/refda...', Array)",
>           "#16 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))",
>           "#17 F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\api\web\index.php(35): yii\base\Application->run()",
>           "#18 {main}"
>       ]
>   }

I have looked at this problem in detail and tried this [solution](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/cookievalidationkey-must-be-configured-with-a-secret-key/72312/2)  in my `config/main.php`

```
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ .'/main-local.php')
);
'components' => [
        'request' => [

            'enableCookieValidation' => false,
            'enableCsrfValidation' => false,

        ],    


'request' => [

'enableCookieValidation' => false,// also set it to true

'enableCsrfValidation' => false, // also set it to true
],
```

In `/config/main-local.php` I have following

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'someRandomKey', 

    ],
],
```

It's not working for me. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: 'enableCookieValidation' => true,
            'enableCsrfValidation' => true, add in main local and check

Comment: tried but having same issue again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `request` component from the `common/config/main-local.php` and just keep it into the `frontend/config/main-local.php`.

Then add the following in your `api/config/main.php` under `components` to turn off cookie validation for the API.

```
 'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'enableCookieValidation' => false,
            'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
        ],
```